# Google+ Domains API - You do not have permission to execute this method.

Tags: google-api, google-plus-domains

Enabled Google+ Domains API.
Added Restrictions URL.

But still when i try this API from google api-explorer and python code both the result is throwing this error.

```
403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Anybody can help us.

Answer (score 0):

The user you are authenticated as does not have a Google domains account.   Try and run authentication again with the correct user.

Note: Google+ domains is like google apps and gsuite.   It is not Google+ the social media website.

Comment: Is there any other way to get "Google domains account". I just create project from my account  and enabled google plus domain.

Comment: https://admin.google.com/accountchooser?consumerAccountUsed=true sign in here you have to pay for it.